# Regex extraction data before vs after comma in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am a regex beginner, as I don't usually process text. I have a very simple question. I managed to construct the following regex to extract data after a comma:

```
sub('.*,\\s*','', X)
```

where X is the column I am searching.

I now separately want to extract the data before the comma, but am struggling with the regex syntax. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Some example data and desired result would be good.

Comment: You haven't given an example of your data but `strsplit` by comma might be a more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following expression:

```
sub('\\s*,.*','', X)
```

replaces everything from the last comma to the end of line with an empty string. Therefore, it will return the text before the last comma in the string.

Comment: Thanks both for the help

Answer (score 3):

Your regex

```
sub('.*,\\s*','', X)
```

is not extracting text, it is **substituting** the second param for what is **matched** by the first. So, everything that matches a bunch of characters followed by a comma followed by a space character in `X` gets replaced with nothing in this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/bB9kJ2/1).

You can see what you are hitting in the demo linked above. I am not certain what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to match the text that sits before a comma in your text, [this](https://regex101.com/r/bB9kJ2/3) regex will match it and here is how you would also replace it with your previous replacement in your `sub`

In R

```
X2 = "here is another test string, with following text"
Y <- sub('.*(,.*)','', X2)
```

yielding

```
> Y
[1] ", with following text"
```

In R, your code produces:

```
X = "here is a test string, "
Y <- sub('.*,\\s*','\\1', X)
```

yielding

```
> Y
[1] ""
```